# Scalar multiplication - Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static int[][] scalarMultiplication(int[][] A,int num) {
    int[][] arrayScalarMul = new int[A.length][A[0].length];

    for (int x=0; x < arrayScalarMul.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < arrayScalarMul[x].length; y++) {
            arrayScalarMul[x][y] = A[x * num][y * num];
        }
    }
    return arrayScalarMul;
}
```

As the title says I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error, I see some people fix it by making on of the lengths shorter by 1, I just don't get why thats needed ?

Comment: surely `x * num` or `y * num` *aren't [always] valid indexes* .. read the exception. love the exception. it *doesn't* lie. question is "too localized", but hopefully the answers give some ideas on how to fix this issue .. and then hopefully this question is closed/deleted.

Answer (score 5):

```
arrayScalarMul[x][y] = A[x * num][y * num];
```

Change it to

```
arrayScalarMul[x][y] = num * A[x][y];
```

You are multiplying the index with given scalar, but you should multiply with the value on that index.

Comment: Isn't that an assumption that original intention was to multiply each index value by num? I thought he wanted to access A[x*num][y*num] provided that is a valid index and use that value?

Comment: `Scalar Multiplication` doesn't work that way. Based on title, i'll say my assumption is correct.

Comment: err - Yeah. Makes sense. Didn't focus on that

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of

arrayScalarMul[x][y] = A[x * num][y * num];

num when multiplied with x (or y) takes it out of bounds.

The index-1 termination is usually used to prevent  "off by 1 error" where because you have a 0 based array, so an array of size n, would actually have valid index ranging between 0 and n-1. So either we use loop condition of < n or <= n-1. This is not the case above.

If your intension is to replace value at A[x][y] with A[x*num][y*num], *provided this is a valid index*, then add a check like this

```
if(x*num - totalx) && (y*num - totaly)
   A[x][y] = A[x*num][y*num];
```

Answer (score 0):

*lengths shorter by 1* also will not work as `num` is variable here.

```
arrayScalarMul[x][y] = A[x * num][y * num];
```

It producing `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here *x*num* and *y* num* goes beyond of array index.